# What's the shorter version for python dict checking key exist then get value?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
if key in dict and dict[key]==value:
```

For the above, if statement, we first need to check the key that exists in dict then get the value. I'm curious do we have a shorter version or a better way for this?

Comment: If your values are not `None` you'd use `dict.get(key) == value`. But your code is readable and the intention is very clear. It's pythonic imo.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dict.get()`. It will return `None` if the key doesn't exist rather than raising an exception.

```
if dict.get(key) == value:
```

This will work as long as `None` isn't an actual value you might be comparing with, because you can't tell the difference between it being returned by default or from the dictionary. In that case, you need to provide some value that isn't a possible value. You could provide an empty object, since that creates a new list that can't be the same as one in the dictionary.

```
if dict.get(key, object()) == value:
```

Comment: Instead of `[]` would it be better to use `object()`?

Comment: Any unique value is fine, and `[]` is shorter.

Comment: Got you. `[]`, `None` are very commonly used. `object()` is rarely used(assumption from my limited experience). I got the point `[]` is just a placeholder in your answer it could be anything OP could use as they see fit.

Comment: I don't get the usage of empty list. True that it can't be identical to another value, but it can still be equal to another empty list, and it's equality that matters here.

Comment: Oops, you're right. I was thinking of JavaScript, where arrays are compared by identity, not contents.

Comment: @Ch3steR You were right, because lists are compared by contents, so `[] == []` is true.